# Log in with either a password or a public key. But not both at the same time, and limit the PAM authentication to the root user

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys

I am having difficulties configuring the ssh server. The scenario is as follows. The root user is the only one using google F2A (PAM), the restricted user only connects by password and the rest of the users connect without password (because they dont have), only with the public key. However I need to create a user (otheruser) that must be able to log in with either password or public key. But not both at the same time and without F2A. This is the sshd_config file I have. The point of this sshd service is to use as a jump server (SSH Tunnel).

```
    Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
    PermitRootLogin yes
    UsePAM yes
    X11Forwarding yes
    PrintMotd no
    AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
    Subsystem sftp  /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
    PermitTunnel yes
    AllowTcpForwarding yes
    LogLevel VERBOSE
    SyslogFacility AUTH
    
    Match User root
            AuthenticationMethods keyboard-interactive:pam
    
    Match User restricted
            AuthenticationMethods password
    
    Match User otheruser
            AuthenticationMethods publickey,password
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, in the pam.d/sshd file, add "nullok" at the end of the line auth required pam_google_authenticator.so. I also removed:

```
 Match User otheruser 
     AuthenticationMethods publickey,password
```

With this configuration, users can log in with their public key or password. Root can only log in with a password and two-factor authentication (keyboard-interactive:pam) which is defined by the Match User root block. And the user restricted can access only with a password.